# Frustrations with sorting questions/answers by score

Tags: bug, profile-page

I was recently hunting for an old answer of mine, and remembered it as being relatively high-scoring. To find it, I went to my answer list on my profile page, and sorted it by score. My answers were sorted by score, but the order in which answers of the same score appeared in the list seemed to be random.

This wasn't a problem, until I noticed that, when I changed from page 1 to page 2 of my answers, the page would re-roll the order of these questions! I would see, on the next page, answers that I had seen on the previous page. This means that I'm not seeing the complete list! Some answers were moving from page 1 to page 2 and back again, so that I wasn't seeing them.

I tested this with the questions page of two other users (to make sure it wasn't just my profile, and that it wasn't just the answers page). On one, I couldn't replicate the behaviour, but on the other, I could. I have no idea why.

I don't think this should be expected behaviour.

Comment: Small disclaimer: It is entirely possible that my specific combination of ad-blockers, cookie-deleters, javascript blockers, etc, broke the web page in a very specific way. I have whitelisted MSE in most respects, and the site functions perfectly normally for me (this notwithstanding), but I still have had whitelisted sites fail to work. Normally, however, if my setup is a problem, the site usually just refuses to load, rather than working perfectly fine for years, only to throw up a slight, weird bug.

Comment: I can reproduce this kind of behavior for the OP's profile in Firefox private mode, so I don't think this caused by javascript blockers and the like.

Comment: Thanks for checking, @MaoWao.

Comment: Explicitly, OP's 10-score answers are split between pages 1 and 2. switching back and forth, I saw [pg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4v0J.png), [pg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrzsA.png), then [pg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/878Yg.png), and finally [pg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KHfK.png) again. Observe "Is there a way to solve composite exponential equations precisely?" is **only** in the fourth screenshot.

Comment: If you want to put this in the main body, `Explicitly, OP's 10-score answers are split between pages 1 and 2. switching back and forth, I saw [pg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4v0J.png), [pg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrzsA.png), then [pg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/878Yg.png), and finally [pg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KHfK.png) again. Observe "Is there a way to solve composite exponential equations precisely?" is **only** in the fourth screenshot. `

Comment: I see the same thing on my computer. I don't think it has anything to do with your setup. The Activity page was redesigned last December, and there have been issues ever since.  MathJax still doesn't display properly in several places.

Comment: To get the attention of a developer, this might need to be posted on the [main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RandomVariable I think if a moderator tags this with the ([meta-tag:status-review]) tag, then it will serve the same purpose.

Comment: This is still an issue.  I was looking for a particular answer of mine today, and I was having trouble finding it.  In addition, MathJax is still broken on the "Summary" tab.

Comment: This issue has still not been fixed, and it probably won't be fixed until they decide to redesign the Activity page again.  It's an incredibly annoying issue that has the effect of hiding posts.