# Why is MathJax parsing incorrectly for this linked question?

Tags: bug, mathjax, linked-questions

In the linked questions to [Sum of the series $\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^k.(k+1).(k+2).\binom{n}{r-k} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/339213/91818), I get:

> [image]

but the correct parsing of the title is [Find the remainder when $\sum_{r=0}^{2014} \sum_{k=0}^r (-1)^k (k+1)(k+2)\binom{2019}{r-k}$ is divided by 64](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4493578/91818):

> [image]

I uploaded a video of my clicking refresh [here](https://player.vimeo.com/video/730546349?h=f952b96618).  At first it's okay, then it changes to the incorrect version.

I'm on Firefox.  Changing my zoom doesn't affect anything.

**Question**: Why is MathJax parsing incorrectly for this linked question?

Comment: This has been a problem since the new responsive design. Many instances of this bug have been reported here and on Meta SE, but not all of them have been fixed, unfortunately…

Comment: For example, this [status-completed] (sic) post: [Multiline MathJax on Title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/multiline-mathjax-on-title)

Comment: I'm not sure if they have been messing with it or its device dependent, but I cannot reproduce on my end the error *in the Linked Questions link*. Yet, I do see it in my [Summary page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGSMO.png), which was mentioned [before](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34508/multiline-mathjax-on-title#comment161518_34508). It may also affect some [other](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34510/displays-on-main-question-page?noredirect=1#comment161381_34510) [pages](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34508/multiline-mathjax-on-title#comment161596_34518).

Comment: Try switching to the CommonHTML or SVG renderer using the MathJax contextual menu via the Math Settings->Math Renderer submenus.  When the HTML-CSS renderer breaks an inline expression, it creates a box that is only as wide as the split equation (as an inline box aligned on the top line), and there can be space after it that gets filled with the rest of the sentence.  That gives the strange breaking effect that you see: "is divided" follows the box containing the broken equation, and "by 64" falls below).  The other renderers make full-width boxes, so should make for better layout.

Comment: I just noticed that changing the renderer creates a new issue on the Summary page.  Sometimes the MathJax in a title under "Questions" doesn't display and the date gets pushed to the right.

Comment: @RandomVariable yes, in fact my "19 hours ago" is [pushed out of the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCjWJ.png). Still, this is preferrable to my [earlier screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGSMO.png)

Comment: @CalvinKhor   When I sort my questions by activity, one of the dates gets pushed completely out of the box.

Comment: Perhaps this issue has resolved itself in the meantime?

Comment: To answer my own [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34975/why-is-mathjax-parsing-incorrectly-for-this-linked-question#comment165314_34975), no, this issue is [not resolved](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/revisions/5246/2). This being the case, I'm surprised that my flag on this post (raised on Jul 16 itself) requesting to have the [status-review] tag added to it was declined two days ago for the reason that "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Comment: @TheAmplitwist   It has indeed not been resolved.  The "Summary" tab on my Activity page is still a mess.  Changing the renderer is not the solution because it just creates other issues on the Activity page and elsewhere.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist   Incredibly the issue is still not resolved. I almost feel like I'm being disrespected when I got to the "Summary" tab of my Activity page and continue to see that it's all messed up. Also, the [issue](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34952/16033) of what happens when you sort questions or answers by score hasn't been resolved either.

Comment: @RandomVariable I've learned to live with it now...

Comment: @TheAmplitwist   What's more frustrating than the issue itself is that you can't get a Stack Exchange developer to look at the issue, which I know is fixable because it was fixed for a couple weeks last February.